# How to connect cell vertical lines of a table in latex

Tags: latex

In the Following table, I am experiencing a disconnection in the vertical cell lines as shown in the image.

```
\begin{table*}[!htb]
  \caption{}
  \begin{center}
  \label{tab:Apps}
  %\small\setlength\tabcolsep{6pt}
    \begin{tabular}
{|p{0.13\textwidth}|p{0.43\textwidth}|p{0.15\textwidth}|p{0.18\textwidth}|}
  %  \toprule
   %\hline


     \hline
       \centering{\textbf{Text}} & \centering {\textbf{Text}} & \centering{\textbf{Text}} &\textbf{Text}\\
       \hline
       \begin{flushright}\centering Text \vspace*{-3pt} \end{flushright} & \vspace{-2pt}\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*, noitemsep, topsep=0pt] \item Text. \vspace*{-1.7\baselineskip} \end{itemize} &  \begin{flushright}\centering Text \vspace*{-3pt} \end{flushright} &  \begin{flushright}\centering Text \vspace*{-3pt} \end{flushright} & \\
       \hline
\begin{flushright}\centering Text \vspace*{-3pt} \end{flushright} & \vspace{-2pt}\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*, noitemsep, topsep=0pt] \item Text. \vspace*{-1.7\baselineskip} \end{itemize} &  \begin{flushright}\centering Text \vspace*{-3pt} \end{flushright} &  \begin{flushright}\centering Text \vspace*{-3pt} \end{flushright} & \\
       \hline
  
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table*}
```

[image]

Comment: Please make a compilable [mre]

Comment: Thank you. I added the code that I used to create my table. Any help why I am getting disconnected lines in the table.